# jquery select-box - how can I have two inputs different widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using this jquery plugin to make my select dropdown boxes look nicer. http://code.google.com/p/select-box/

Here's a fiddle of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/1/

I want to have the two dropdowns to be different widths but I've tried wrapping them in divs, tried to hack the js to give them different ids, everything I can think of but no joy.

Also I'm ashamed to admit I can't seem to change the color of the text in the actual dropdown bit. I can change the backgound colour etc but buggered if I can change the color of the text... weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option that you can specify what to use as classname for the `sbHolder` object, but you don't want to change that since you would need to rewrite the CSS. It'd be nice if they let you set an additional class to apply, but they don't.

I would just put a wrapper around the select element and use CSS to override the default width http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/8/

```
.wrapper-one .sbHolder{
    width: 500px;
}

.wrapper-two .sbHolder {
    width: 200px;
}


<div class="wrapper-one">
<select id="language">
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option value="objective-c">Objective C</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div class="wrapper-two">
<select id="language2">
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option value="objective-c">Objective C</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This requires adding some markup, @cih's answer doesn't. It just requires using jQuery to mark each instance accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/37/

```
$("#language").selectbox();
$("#language2").selectbox();

$(".sbHolder").each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('instance-' + index);
});

.instance-0.sbHolder{
    width: 500px;
}

.instance-1.sbHolder {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this! Works :) and ideas about changing the text color in the dropdown.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox You shouldn't keep adding questions to a question, one question per post is best. Just override the `color` property in the corresponding selector, here's a clue: this is how they do it: `.sbOptions a:hover,.sbOptions a:focus,.sbOptions a.sbFocus{ color: #EBB52D;}` Follow the same pattern

Comment: the color thing doesn't work. Ive tried tinkering with all the color selectors in all the different classes and ids but nothing seems to be able to change the text color. Give it a go yourself, it's weird!

Comment: Hey there, since this answers my initial question the best I'm marking it right. I've also taken your advice and asked a seperate question about the text color. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sbHolder").first().addClass("first");
```

That will add a class you can target on you first checkbox, there better way to iterate through multiple selectors, check out [this link..](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no)

Other than that Joe answers the rest of your question.

Comment: Doing it with JS is kind of cheating, but gets the job done. See my answer for a pure CSS alternative

Comment: Yep your answer is the clean solution, mine is the quick win... Time and a place for both in my opinion :-)

Comment: That's why I said, it gets the job done. Thinking about it harder, it's not even that bad, since you're not setting the width from JS. This solution is better in the sense that you don't need extra markup

Comment: I created a JS fiddle with your example and pasted it in my answer. Feel free to copy it to yours since you had the idea initially.

Comment: Cheers, but your answer is the most complete now so better that gets accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/30/

```
<link href="http://select-box.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.2/jquery.selectbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://select-box.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.2/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>


<select id="language">
 <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
 <option value="objective-c">Objective C</option>
 <option value="python">Python</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

<select id="language2">
  <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
  <option value="objective-c">Objective C</option>
  <option value="python">Python</option>
 </select>


  ##### JQUERY #######
      $(function () {
        $("#language").selectbox();
        $("#language2").selectbox();
        $(".sbHolder").each(function(){
          var $langDom = $(this);
          if($langDom.prev().attr('id') == 'language'){
            $langDom.addClass("language_1");  
          } else if($langDom.prev().attr('id') == 'language2') {
            $langDom.addClass("language_2");          
         }
       });
     });

    ###### CSSS TO ADD #####
   .language_1{
     width: 1200px;
    }

    .language_2{
      width: 200px;
     }
```

​

Comment: You're applying `language_x` to the `select` which is made invisible.

Comment: @JuanMendes I am not applying language_x to select. I am applying that to the dom which has class sbHolder

Comment: I see, I got confused with the call to `prev()` in there

Answer (score 0):

For the text color, change `.sbOptions a:link, .sbOptions a:visited {}` and/or `.sbOptions a:hover, .sbOptions a:focus, .sbOptions a.sbFocus {}`.

For the widths, `.sbOptions` is your dropdown width, and `.sbHolder {}` is the width of the "currently selected" item.

Comment: Doesn't help with creating two separate widths, if you look at the fiddle the OP posted, they already know about the CSS classes to override

Comment: Ah, I read "different widths" as in "not whatever it is there". More specificity on the selector should allow them to be different widths though.

Comment: @cih Don't use references like above, the order of answers change. Joe, you would need to explain what you mean by more specififity (and improve your answer, not just make a comment)

Comment: Hi there, this doesn't work strangely. This is why I'm having problems with it, I tried all that but weirdly, it dun't work! :(